# How can copy Blobstore to another application?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

I need carry out cloning application. Datastore can copy through
AppEngine console. How can copy Blobstore to another application?

Answer (score 1):

Google does not provide a bulk option for download and upload the blobstore. Because of that you need to write your own code which do the procedure.

I can think about an upload endpoint in the destination application and an endpoint, in the source application, which cycle throgh the existing blob (you can know the existing blobs making a query on the datastore on the `BlobInfo` entity kind).

Remember that if you re-upload a blob in another application the `BlobKey` is not maintained, so you'll need to update your datastore entities too.

Because of the deprecation of the Blobstore, you can think about move to Cloud Storage in the source application first (changing the stored BlobKeys in a bucket/object Storage value) and then, after you have transferred the Datastore, you simply need to give access to the bucket to the destination application (only if you want keep the same file on two different applications)